# While typing number in my android app without any log app closed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-softkeyboard

I have Android app with signup page and edit profile page, After installing my app complete the signup process then edit the profile page after login,

When I type number the app closes immediately without any logs and my logcat response is

```
02-23 21:50:23.530 2784-2784/? W/AllCapsTransformationMethod: Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
02-23 21:50:23.530 2784-2784/? W/AllCapsTransformationMethod: Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
02-23 21:50:23.540 1663-1820/? I/LatinIME:LogUtils: Dictionary info: dictionary = spellcheck_contacts.en_US ; version = 1456244423 ; date = ?
02-23 21:50:23.550 1359-1492/? I/AccountManagerService: getTypesVisibleToCaller: isPermitted? true
02-23 21:50:23.550 1663-1820/? I/LatinIME:LogUtils: Dictionary info: dictionary = spellcheck_userunigram.en_US ; version = 1456244423 ; date = ?
02-23 21:50:23.570 1663-1820/? I/LatinIME:LogUtils: Dictionary info: dictionary = main:en ; version = 54 ; date = 1414726273
02-23 21:50:23.710 2784-2784/? W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ImageView{6cbdb3c V.ED..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f0d01d9 app:id/selector} during layout: running second layout pass
02-23 21:50:23.710 2784-2784/? W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ImageView{e00d0c5 V.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0d01d9 app:id/selector} during layout: running second layout pass
02-23 21:50:23.710 2784-2784/? W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ImageView{3531a1a V.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0d01d9 app:id/selector} during layout: running second layout pass
02-23 21:50:23.710 2784-2784/? W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ImageView{672394b V.ED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0d01d9 app:id/selector} during layout: running second layout pass
02-23 21:50:28.380 1663-1663/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = 0,0
02-23 21:50:28.420 1663-2847/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-23 21:50:28.420 1663-2847/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f4c03a98140, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-23 21:50:30.510 1032-1032/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1032: eglCreateSyncKHR(1252): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
02-23 21:50:30.530 1663-1663/? I/LatinIME: Starting input. Cursor position = -1,-1
02-23 21:50:30.550 1359-1373/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 2352:com.android.messaging/u0a48 (adj 15): empty #17
02-23 21:50:30.640 1701-1962/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-23 21:50:30.640 1701-1962/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe037d300, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-23 21:50:30.660 2784-2824/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f4bf173ca90
02-23 21:50:30.740 1663-2847/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f4c03cd9ec0
02-23 21:50:36.280 1701-1701/? I/Choreographer: Skipped 334 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

My Edit profile layout file

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/save_zip_name_edit_text"
    style="@style/CheckrSignUpAnswerEditTextView"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    />
```

Has anyone the idea about this issue?

Comment: if you are trying in emulator then also try it in real device also as emulator just closes like this many times without any error

Comment: I tried both emulator and real devices(One plus)

Comment: do you have any imageview in your layout?

Comment: yes I have image view in fragment under tabbed menu I have 4 fragments the first fragment is edit profile

Comment: @Aruljothi Can you remove the `style` and try running the app?

Comment: in log it says requestLayout called improperly on imageview. Check that

Comment: @BlazingFire Still issue exits thanks